# Проблемы с внедрением одной FXML-сцены в другую

Tags: javafx, kotlin, fxml, tornadofx

Пробую на зуб `TornadoFX` (да и котлин в целом) и встретился с одной проблемой. У меня есть основная сцена с `TabPane` и вкладки в ней это отдельные сцены со своими контроллерами. Когда я делал это средствами `JavaFx` все было нормально, но аналогичный процесс в торнадо прошел не так гладко. Если в `JavaFX` сцена растягивается на всю площадь таба, то в торнадо - нет (сохраняет базовый размер).

`FXML` тот же (разве что объявление контроллера убрал). Внедрение нового таба в торнадо делаю следующим кодом:

```
val scene = find(SomeController::class.java)
scene.mainController = this

tab = Tab(customName, scene.root)
```

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в самом FXML. `SceneBuilder` по умолчанию проставляет следующие поля в корневой ноде:

```
maxHeight="-Infinity" 
maxWidth="-Infinity" 
minHeight="-Infinity" 
minWidth="-Infinity" 
prefHeight="400.0" 
prefWidth="600.0"
```

Если загружать и внедрять такой fxml силами JavaFX, они, судя по всему, игнорируются. Но TornadoFX их учитывает и в итоге сцена не растягивается на весь Tab. **Т.е. эти поля из корневой ноды лучше удалить.**